# How many epsilon numbers $<\omega_1$ are there?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

An epsilon number is an ordinal $\epsilon$ such that $\epsilon=\omega^\epsilon.$ What is the cardinality of the set of all epsilon numbers less than $\omega_1$?

I'm asking this because of a proof I've just read that seems to presuppose that there are countably many such ordinals, and it seems to me intuitively that there should be uncountably many (although I don't know how to prove it).

**Added.** OK, I've just understood that the proof I mentioned is OK even if there are uncountably many such ordinals, but I still don't see how I can find their number.

Comment: $\omega_1$.${}$

Comment: @Andres Thank you, that's what I thought. But how can I prove it?

Comment: OK, finally found it. The reason why I do not like the standard answer (as the ones below) is that it uses choice (in the form: The countable union of countable sets is countable), but the fact that there are $\omega_1$-many $\varepsilon$-numbers below $\omega_1$ does not need choice. This was asked on this site before, here is the link: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/181424/462

Comment: Now, this is mostly a pet peeve of mine, but I think it is useful to be aware of these things. Let me go further: There is a standard trick to show that some results using choice do not require it. It is metamathematical, we move between the universe and an inner model of choice, and check that whatever relevant facts verified in the inner model hold in the universe. This is the shape of Joel's answer in the link above, which is why I prefer tomasz's, since it is purely combinatorial. For another example, see here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40507/distinct-well-orderings-of-the-same-set

Comment: Andres, the problem in this case with moving up and down between $L$ and $V$ is that the only time we need this is when $\omega_1$ is singular, in which case $\omega_1^L\neq\omega_1$, so the proof requires some augmentation. I think, whoever, that one can probably prove an interesting lemma that if the ordinals are an iterative sequence like the one in my answer, then we can uniformly enumerate them, in which case no choice is needed in proving their limit is countable.

Comment: @Andres: Ah, actually no trick is needed. Ordinal arithmetics are absolute, so even if $\omega_1^L\neq\omega_1$, in $L$ there is a bijection between the $\varepsilon$ numbers which are smaller than $\omega_1^V$ and $\omega_1^V$, which would witness there are $\aleph_1$ countable $\varepsilon$ numbers in $V$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that $\varepsilon_0$ is countable. So if there are only countably many countable $\varepsilon$ numbers, they would have a countable supremum, $\alpha$. Consider now the same construction as $\varepsilon_0$, starting $\alpha+1$. That is:
$$\sup\{\omega^{\alpha+1},\omega^{\omega^{\alpha+1}},\ldots\}$$

The result is itself an $\varepsilon$ number, and it is countable (as the countable limit of countable ordinals). But all the countable $\varepsilon$ numbers were assumed to be below $\alpha$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: The beginning of this answer seems mis-stated. There are a proper class of epsilon numbers, but this question is asking about the set of all epsilon numbers less than $\omega_1$.

Comment: Seems where, and how?

Comment: "If there are only countably many $\varepsilon$ numbers"

Comment: @Mario: Yes, this is what we call "proof by contradiction". Of course I'd meant to say that if there were only countably many countable $\varepsilon$ numbers, but those are the ones the question is interested in anyway.

Comment: I know, and I don't otherwise have an issue with your proof. I just thought I'd mention it as a minor typo.

Answer (score 6):

Your intuition is correct: $\omega_1=\epsilon_{\omega_1}$. See the discussion in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_numbers_(mathematics)): the constructions of $\epsilon_{\alpha+1}$ from $\epsilon_\alpha$ and of $\epsilon_\alpha$ for a countable limit ordinal $\alpha$ preserve countability, so there must be $\omega_1$ countable $\epsilon$-numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer that uses choice:

Since $\varepsilon_\alpha$ is countable if $\alpha$ is countable by [this other SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/181424/462) or by the arguments in the other answers (and obviously $\varepsilon_\alpha\ge\alpha$), the map $f:\beta\to\omega_1$ defined by $f(\alpha)=\varepsilon_\alpha$ (where $\beta$ is the number of countable $\varepsilon$ numbers) is a cofinal map. But by the axiom of choice, $\omega_1$ is regular. Thus there are $\beta=\omega_1$ countable $\varepsilon$ numbers.

Comment: I have to admit that I have no idea what does $\alpha\mapsto\epsilon_\alpha:\beta\to\omega_1$ means.

Comment: @AsafKaragila This is the function from $\beta$ to $\omega_1$, defined by mapping each $\alpha<\beta$ to $\epsilon_\alpha<\omega_1$.

Comment: Mario, why is $\epsilon_\alpha$ countable if $\alpha$ is countable? (Isn't this the point?)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo This follows from, e.g. [your link](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/181424/462). I'm just filling in the remaining steps to find the cardinality of the countable $\varepsilon$ numbers.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I've made my notation a bit more standard.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro You should probably specify this in the body of the question, to indicate that it is not meant to be self-contained, but to provide some details you feel are missing from the other answer(s).