# Existence of countable ordinal

Tags: ordinals

Prove that there exist countable ordinal $\xi$ such that $\xi=\omega^\xi$. 
The $\xi= \sup \{b^i \mid b_1=w, b_{i+1}=w^{b^i}\}$ should work. But how to prove that $\xi$ is countable?

Comment: If you use the usual representation of ordinals as sets, you can write the $\sup$ as a union, and use that countable unions of countable sets are countable, I think.

Comment: I think countable union of countable sets is countable, if you assume countable Axiom of Choise

Comment: Are you assuming the axiom of choice?

Comment: The reason I ask is that, yes, if you assume the axiom of choice, the statement is straightforward, as $\epsilon_0$ is the countable union of countable ordinals. The point here is that you should be able to show easily that $\alpha^\beta$ is countable if both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are countable, using for instance [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/278997/462) characterization of ordinal exponentiation.

Comment: There was no mention about AC so I suppose we cannot assume it.

Comment: However, if you do not assume the axiom of choice, then one needs to work a bit harder, and verify that we get (uniformly) enumerations for all of $\omega^\omega,\omega^{\omega^{\omega}},\dots$, simultaneously, so we can implement the prof that countable unions of countable sets are countable, but without invoking the axiom of choice.

Comment: (There is also a lazy way of avoiding choice. In the constructible universe $L$, choice holds, so $\epsilon_0$ is countable there. Check that ordinal exponentiation is absolute, so $\epsilon_0$ is computed the same in $V$ and in $L$, and of course the enumeration in $L$ still verifies that $\epsilon_0$ is countable in $V$.)

Comment: OK. This question has been asked here a few times before. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/181424/462) is a link to one of those instances. I suggest you study tomasz's answer, as it does not require knowledge of absoluteness or constructibility, and explicitly indicates how to produce the uniform enumerations I alluded to above.